# 1.4.3 hyper ledger fabric specific binary not avaiable to download?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

===> 
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b

--->> Checking out v1.4.3 of hyperledger/fabric-samples
HEAD is now at f86ec95 [FAB-16390] Added filter for invalid transactions

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 1.4.3 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.3/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.3.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 1.4.3 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----

Comment: It may be because of the Content delivery backend is down could you try again?

Comment: yes i have tried many times

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this curl command

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.4 1.4.4 0.4.18
```

Comment: what is your VM architecture and OS details?

Comment: i am using without vm ..ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Comment: Something from your Ubuntu machine has a problem please check hyperledger side is fine. Try to download some other file using curl